# Is there a more efficient way to scrape this html table into a dataframe?

Tags: python, html, json, logging, scrapy

I wrote this code to scrape from a game database at [here](https://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/).

It actually works pretty well, and I'm able to scrape the data and manipulate it appropriately, but it seems like I must be doing it in an inefficient way because it spits out the data I want 50 times over... Let me explain:

Below is the code for my crawler:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('gamesresult.jl', 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item


class VGSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "game_spider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/']

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 1}, # Used for pipeline 1
        'FEED_FORMAT':'json',                                 # Used for pipeline 2
        'FEED_URI': 'gamesresult.json'                        # Used for pipeline 2
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        TABLE_SELECTOR = ('//*[@id="generalBody"]/table[1]/tr')

        table = response.xpath(TABLE_SELECTOR)


        IMAGE_SELECTOR = '//td[2]/div/a/div/img/@src'
        TITLE_SELECTOR = '//td[3]/a/text()'
        CONSOLE_SELECTOR = '//td[4]/img/@alt'
        PUBLISHER_SELECTOR = '//td[5]/text()'
        VGSCORE_SELECTOR = '//td[6]/text()'
        CRITIC_SELECTOR = '//td[7]/text()'
        USER_SELECTOR = '//td[8]/text()'
        TOTALSHIPPED_SELECTOR = '//td[9]/text()'
        RELEASE_SELECTOR = '//td[10]/text()'
        UPDATE_SELECTOR = '//td[11]/text()'

        yield {
            'img' : table.xpath(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'title' : table.xpath(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'console' : table.xpath(CONSOLE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'publisher' : table.xpath(PUBLISHER_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'vg_score' : table.xpath(VGSCORE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'critic_score' : table.xpath(CRITIC_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'user_score' : table.xpath(USER_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'total_shipped' : table.xpath(TOTALSHIPPED_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'release_date' : table.xpath(RELEASE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'last_update' : table.xpath(UPDATE_SELECTOR).extract()
            }

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(VGSpider)
process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
```

Here is the source html from the page:

```
<td style="font-size:12pt;">    <a href="https://www.vgchartz.com/game/226034/pokemon/?region=All" >Pokemon    </a>  </td>
            <td align="center">

<img src="/images/consoles/Series_b.png" alt="Series">
            </td>  
<td width="100">Nintendo  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">365.60m</td>  
<td width="75" align="center">28th Sep 98  </td>  
<td width="75" align="center">03rd Feb 20</td></tr><tr style="background-image:url(../imgs/chartBar_alt_large.gif); height:70px">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
              <div id="photo3">
                <a href="/games/game.php?id=226187&region=All">
                  <div style="height:60px; width:60px; overflow:hidden;">          <img src="/games/boxart/full_4441628AmericaFrontccc.jpg" border="0" width="60" alt="Boxart Missing">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>  
<td style="font-size:12pt;">    
<a href="https://www.vgchartz.com/game/226187/super-mario/?region=All" >Super Mario    </a>  </td>
            <td align="center">

<img src="/images/consoles/Series_b.png" alt="Series">
            </td>  
<td width="100">Nintendo  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">N/A  </td>  
<td align="center">356.59m</td>  
<td width="75" align="center">20th Jul 83  </td>  
<td width="75" align="center">20th Feb 20</td></tr><tr style="background-image:url(../imgs/chartBar_large.gif); height:70px">
```

This spits out into the appropriate json file with essentially the correct information... to an extent. Basically, I get something like the below:

```
{"img": ["/games/boxart/full_4261443AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_4441628AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_9594883AmericaFrontccc.png", "/games/boxart/full_7292379AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_4446063AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_1356677AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_5967679AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_2881264AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_6200477AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_3250466AmericaFrontccc.jpg", "/games/boxart/full_4399408AmericaFrontccc.jpg"...
}
```

Now, this wouldn't be so bad, because I would have a whole column in a list, but it actually includes all of the images in the column, but has each one duplicated 50 times. Is there some loop in my code missing? Why is this info being repeated 50 times? I am definitely able to extract it on the other end but involves me just selecting the first 50 elements in each list. It seems like maybe I've just done something inefficient here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **relative** XPath:

```
def parse(self, response):
    IMAGE_SELECTOR = './/td[2]/div/a/div/img/@src'
    TITLE_SELECTOR = './/td[3]/a/text()'
    CONSOLE_SELECTOR = './/td[4]/img/@alt'
    PUBLISHER_SELECTOR = './/td[5]/text()'
    VGSCORE_SELECTOR = './/td[6]/text()'
    CRITIC_SELECTOR = './/td[7]/text()'
    USER_SELECTOR = './/td[8]/text()'
    TOTALSHIPPED_SELECTOR = './/td[9]/text()'
    RELEASE_SELECTOR = './/td[10]/text()'
    UPDATE_SELECTOR = './/td[11]/text()'
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="generalBody"]/table[1]/tr'):
        yield {
            'img' : row.xpath(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'title' : row.xpath(TITLE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'console' : row.xpath(CONSOLE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'publisher' : row.xpath(PUBLISHER_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'vg_score' : row.xpath(VGSCORE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'critic_score' : row.xpath(CRITIC_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'user_score' : row.xpath(USER_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'total_shipped' : row.xpath(TOTALSHIPPED_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'release_date' : row.xpath(RELEASE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'last_update' : row.xpath(UPDATE_SELECTOR).extract()
        }
```